# Growable multidimensional data structure supporting range queries

Tags: java, data-structures

Let me put the question first: considering the situation and requirements I'll describe further down, what data structures would make sense/help achieving the non-functional requirements?

I tried to look up several structures but wasn't very successful so far, which might be due to me missing some terminology.

Since we'll implement that in Java any answers should take that into account (e.g. no pointer-magic, assume 8-byte references etc.).

**The situation**

We have somewhat large set of values that are mapped via a 4-dimensional key (let's call those dimensions A, B, C and D). Each dimension can have a different size, so we'll assume the following:

- A: 100
- B: 5
- C: 10000
- D: 2

This means a completely filled structure would contain 10 million elements. Not considering their size the space needed to hold the references alone would be like 80 megabytes, so that would be considered a lower bound for memory consumption.

We further can assume that the structure won't be completely filled but quite densely.

**The requirements**

Since we build and query that structure quite often we have the following requirements:

- constructing the structure should be fast
- queries on single elements and ranges (e.g. [A1-A5, B3, any C, D0]) should be efficient
- fast deletion of elements isn't required (won't happen too often)
- the memory footprint should be low

**What we already considered**

*kd-trees*

Building such a tree takes some time since it can get quite deep and we'd either have to accept slower queries or take rebalancing measures. Additonally the memory footprint is quite high since we need to hold the complete key in each node (there might be ways to reduce that though).

*Nested maps/map tree*

Using nested maps we could store only the key for each dimension as well as a reference to the next dimension map or the values - effectively building a tree out of those maps. To support range queries we'd keep sorted sets of the possible keys and access those while traversing the tree.

Construction and queries were way faster than with kd-trees but the memory footprint was much higher (as expected).

*A single large map*

An alternative would be to keep the sets for individual available keys and use a single large map instead.

Construction and queries were fast as well but memory consumption was even higher due to each map node being larger (they need to hold all dimensions of a key now).

**What we're thinking of at the moment**

Building insertion-order index-maps for the dimension keys, i.e. we map each incoming key to a new integer index as it comes in. Thus we can make sure that those indices grow one step a time without any gaps (not considering deletions).

With those indices we'd then access a tree of n-dimensional arrays (flattened to a 1-d array of course) - aka n-ary tree. That tree would grow on demand, i.e. if we need a new array then instead of creating a larger one and copying all the data we'd just create the new block. Any needed non-leaf nodes would be created on demand, replacing the root if needed.

Let me illustrate that with an example of 2 dimensions A and B. We'll allocate 2 elements for each dimension resulting in a 2x2 matrix (array of length 4).

Adding the first element A1/B1 we'd get something like this:

```
[A1/B1,null,null,null]
```

Now we add element A2/B2:

```
[A1/B1,null,A2/B2,null]
```

Now we add element A3/B3. Since we can't map the new element to the existing array we'll create a new one as well as a common root:

```
                [x,null,x,null]  
                /        \
[A1/B1,null,A2/B2,null]  [A3/B3,null,null,null]
```

Memory consumption for densely filled matrices should be rather low depending on the size of each array (having 4 dimensions and 4 values per dimension in an array we'd have arrays of length 256 and thus get a maximum tree depth of 2-4 in most cases).

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure will be "quite densely" filled, then I think it makes sense to assume that it will be full. That simplifies things quite a bit. And it's not like you're going to save a lot (or anything) using a sparse matrix representation of a densely filled matrix.

I'd try the simplest possible structure first. It might not be the most memory efficient, but it should be reasonable and quite easy to work with.

First, a simple array of 10,000,000 references. That is (and please pardon the C#, as I'm not really a Java programmer):

```
MyStructure[] theArray = new MyStructure[](10000000);
```

As you say, that's going to consume 80 megabytes.

Next is four different dictionaries (maps, I think, in Java), one for each key type:

```
Dictionary<KeyAType, int> ADict;
Dictionary<KeyBType, int> BDict;
Dictionary<KeyCType, int> CDict;
Dictionary<KeyDType, int> DDict;
```

When you add an element at {A,B,C,D}, you look up the respective keys in the dictionary to get their indexes (or add a new index if that key doesn't exist), and do the math to compute an index into the array. The math is, I think:

```
DIndex + 2*(CIndex + 10000*(BIndex + 5*AIndex));
```

In .NET, dictionary overhead is something like 24 bytes per key. But you only have 11,007 total keys, so the dictionaries are going to consume something like 250 kilobytes.

This should be very quick to query directly, and range queries should be as fast as a single lookup and then some array manipulation.

One thing I'm not clear on is if you want a key, to resolve to the same index with every build. That is, if "foo" maps to index 1 in one build, will it always map to index 1?

If so, you probably should statically construct the dictionaries. I guess it depends on if your range queries always expect things in the same key order.

Anyway, this is a very simple and very effective data structure. If you can afford 81 megabytes as the maximum size of the structure (minus the actual data), it seems like a good place to start. You could probably have it working in a couple of hours.

At best it's all you'll have to do. And if you end up having to replace it, at least you have a working implementation that you can use to verify the correctness of whatever new structure you come up with.

Comment: Thanks, that's basically the direction I was thinking of taking. The matrix being densely filled is indeed a relatively safe assumption, however the number of keys is not. In some cases we might only be storing data for 10 A, 2 B but 20000 C etc. and we sometimes don't know that number before all computations (which should already store the data in the structure) are done. Hence the requirement for the structure to be growable. The keys themselves don't need to be mapped to the same index every time, as they could not be present anyways.

Comment: Short update: we ended up with a similar implementation, i.e. a dictionary/map for each key dimension to an index in the underlying data structure. The data itself isn't a single array but a "tree" of arrays, i.e. dimensions 0 to k-1 contain references to sub arrays while dimension k contains the references to the elements. The arrays are grown by a constant amount (so as not to waste too much memory) when necessary. There are possible optimisations we didn't pursue yet: constant/dynamic growth factors (i.e. doubling the arrays), offsets (i.e. not having the arrays start at index 0), etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are other multidimensional trees that are usually better than kd-trees:[quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), [R*Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R*_tree) (like R-Tree, but much faster for updates) or [PH-Tree](http://www.phtree.org). 
The PH-Tree is like a quadtree, but much more space efficient, scales better with dimensions and depth is limited by maximum bitwidth of values, i.e. maximum '10000' requires 14 bit, so the depth will not be more than 14.

Java implementations of all trees can be found on my repo, either [here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/zoodb-indexes) (quadtree may be a bit buggy) or [here](http://www.phtree.org).

**EDIT**
The following optimization can probably be ignored. Of course the described query will result in a full scan, but that may not be as bad as it sounds, because it will on average anyway return 33%-50% of the whole tree.

Possible optimisation (not tested, but might work for the PH-Tree):

One problem with range queries is the different selectivity of your dimensions, which may result in something to a full scan of the tree. For example when querying for [0..100][0..5][0..10000][1..1], i.e. constraining only the last dimension (with least selectivity).

To avoid this, especially for the PH-Tree, I would try to multiply your values by a fixed constant. For example multiply A by 100, B by 2000, C by 1 and D by 5000. This allows all values to range from 0 to 10000, which *may* improve query performance when constraining only dimensions with low selectivity (the 2nd or 4th).

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely have a closer look at R*Trees and the PH-Tree. There's a problem with multiplying the values though: they are arbitrary objects so multiplication is not directly possible (I could try and maintain another level of indirection so the tree would store indices which then could be multiplied).

Comment: The tree only accept long[] (PH-Tree) or double[] (PH-Tree, R*Tree) as keys, you can't use arbitrary objects. If you have to create a new long[] or double[] anyway, multiplying is not a problem. Also, even without multiplying, tree performance may be good enough.

Comment: I realized that the multiplication may not as useful as it sounds, see EDIT above.